# SSTables are never deleted on disk if table gets dropped

Tags: cassandra, tombstone

SSTables are never deleted on disk if table gets deleted.

I had a a table whose tombstones count is >100000 due to which my read queries were throwing Tombstones error. I then dropped the table, but this didn't delete the SSTable files. I re-created the table, then I ran my select queries, I saw the tombstone error again. I don't understand why the old tombstone error has come up again?
Also, when does the SSTable ever gets deleted on disk?

Answer (score 2):

Truncating a table will not remove the SSTable(s) on disk.  You need to run [nodetool cleanup](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsCleanup.html)

Tombstones will disappear through compaction, but only once [gc_grace_seconds](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/tabProp.html) has passed.  The default is 10 days.  Why so long?  Its designed to be a bit longer than a week providing enough time to run repair on a cluster before deletes are discarded.  This maximizes the opportunity for consistency across the nodes.

Comment: I did "drop table xyz", and the corresponding  sstables didnt get deleted from disk. I also run nodetool cleanup, but doesn't help.

Comment: xmas79 is correct that Cassandra will snapshot the data, thus creating hard links.  Use 'nodetool clearsnapshot' to remove either all the snapshots or the ones for specific tables you truncated.  From Linux, 'ls -l' will tell you how many hard links to a file exist.

Comment: I see that the folder for sstables are never deleted, even though all the files (db, index etc) inside it were deleted.And no snapshots were present.  Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

In order to have your tables deleted from disk you need to make sure that no hard-links are currently pointing at them. By default, a `DROP` command will create a snapshot of the CF. You need to set to `false` the `auto_snapshot` property in the YAML file:

```
# Whether or not a snapshot is taken of the data before keyspace truncation
# or dropping of column families. The STRONGLY advised default of true 
# should be used to provide data safety. If you set this flag to false, you will
# lose data on truncation or drop.
auto_snapshot: false
```

If you want err on the safe side (and a general procedure to recreate your keyspace), you could go for:

- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable
- CREATE TABLE mytable (....)
- TRUNCATE mytable

I never had a single problem with this so far.

Comment: I did auto_snapshot: false and restarted Cassandra. Also, Dropped and recreated a table as u said. On dropping or truncating the table, the SStable files are still present on disk, if you goto the data directory of Cassandra and verify. I want to know, why the SStable files for the table still remains on disk and not removed?

Answer (score 0):

Truncate operation is safer than drop and recreate. Truncate may throw a timeout exception, do it again until it is completely done.